# Python class to request multiple websites

Tags: python, function, class, request

I have a request-function `request_url`, which request data from different websites. I apply this function in multiple different functions `some_function_a`.

```
def some_function_a():
     url = www.facebook.com
     facebook = request_url(url)
     facebook.apply(...)  # start to do some data wrangling
     ...

def some_function_b():
     url = www.instagram.com
     instagram = request_url(url)
     instagram.apply(...)
     ...

def some_function_c():
     url = www.linkedin.com
     linkedin = request_url(url)
     linkedin.apply(...)
     ...
```

I would like to pack everything into a class. Unfortunately, I am not very experienced with classes in python. How does a class look like, so that I can do the following:

```
def some_function_a():
    facebook = request_class.facebook
    facebook.apply(...)
    ...

def some_function_b():
    instagram = request_class.instagram
    instagram.apply(...)


def some_function_c():
    linkedin = request_class.linkedin
    linkedin.apply(...)
    ...
```

What would be the most elegant way to do this? How does the class request_class look like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can do something like this (you also need a properly use of requests and urls as strings):

```
class Request_class(object):
    '''
    Class with all the requests
    '''
    def __init__(self, linkedin_url):
        '''
        Constructor
        '''
        #You can pass variables to create some class properties
        #for example, if linkedin url is always the same
        self.linkedin = linkedin_url

    def facebook(self, url):
        facebook = request_url(url)
        facebook.apply(...)
        ...

    def instagram(self, url):
        instagram = request_url(url)
        instagram.apply(...)
        ...

    def linkedin(self):
        #you don't need to pass the linkedin url; it's already a class property
        linkedin = request_url(self.url)
        linkedin.apply(...)
        ...


#Then you can create an instance of the class:
my_requests = Request_class('www.linkedin.com')
#And you can call its methods:
my_requests.facebook('www.facebook.com')
my_requests.instagram('www.instagram.com')
#For this last the class already knows the url
my_requests.linkedin()
```

Answer (score 3):

First create the RequestClass and give it an attribute for url. Then you can create objects using different urls for each site. some_function() can be a class method:

```
class RequestClass:
    def __init__(self, url):
    self.url = url

def make_request(self):
    request(self.url)

def some_function(self):
    apply(...)
```

To create an object:

```
fb = RequestClass("www.facebook.com")

ig = RequestClass("www.instagram.com")

li = RequestClass("www.linkedin.com")

fb.make_request()
ig.make_request()
li.make_request()
```

If you want to have access to the data from the request, you can save it as self.data in your request method assuming the way in which you make requests to the site returns the data:

```
class RequestClass:
    def __init__(self, url):
    self.url = url
    self.data

    def make_request(self):
        self.data = request(self.url)
```

To access the data, for example, from a request from Facebook:

```
fb.data #returns the data from the request to facebook

process_data(fb.data) #easily use that data in a diff function
```

If you create other methods or attributes in the class, you can access them for each site easily, for example if you want to print the data from the request:

```
fb.print_request_data()
ig.print_request_data()
li.print_request_data()
```